# XSLT code not running due to XML namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I found a problem with the namespace and would like to have your help.

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster   xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2" >

  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
        <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free1">679QB</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free2">0.00</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

The XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2"   >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" byte-order-mark="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!-- Copy whole source doc. to target -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 
  <xsl:template match="//*:ItemMasterHeader">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Description|Classification"/>
      <Classification>
        <Codes>
          <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"></Code>
        </Codes>
      </Classification>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my result is

```
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

which is not right since my xslt is to copy the whole doc. to target and insert the RESPQQQ element.

and the following is my expected xml.

```
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
        <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free1">679QB</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free2">0.00</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

Therefore, how do I fix the XSLT in order to have that namespace in XML?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that is really the result you want? With all the elements in no-namespace except the added `Classification` and its descendants, which are in the same namespace as the original XML?

Comment: Sorry, I did make a mistake in my expected xml. Now I re-edited. All I want is to insert the <classification> with RESPQQQ. Thanks.

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:oagis="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2"   >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" byte-order-mark="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- Copy whole source doc. to target -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oagis:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oagis:UserArea">
    <xsl:element name="Classification" xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2">
      <xsl:element name="Codes">
        <xsl:element name="Code">
          <xsl:attribute name="listID">RESPQQQ</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="sequence">1</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster>
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
            <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
            <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
        <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <ItemMaster>
            <ItemMasterHeader>
                <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
                <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
                <Classification>
                    <Codes>
                        <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
                    </Codes>
                </Classification>
                <Classification>
                    <Codes>
                        <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
                    </Codes>
                </Classification>
                <Classification xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2">
                    <Codes>
                        <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
                    </Codes>
                </Classification>
            </ItemMasterHeader>
        </ItemMaster>
    </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

This should be as expected.

Comment: Hi zx485, Thanks for your answer. Actually it was my mistake that my expected result was missing the whole </UserArea> element. How to change your xslt to add the </UserArea> back to xml? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you actually want to do something like this:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2"
xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItemMasterHeader">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Description|Classification"/>
        <Classification>
            <Codes>
                <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
            </Codes>
        </Classification>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will keep all the copied elements in their original namespace and place the added `Classification` element in the same namespace - so that the result is:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="http://schema.xxx.com/xxxOAGIS/2">
   <ApplicationArea>
      <Sender>
         <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
         <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
         <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
      </Sender>
      <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
      <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
   </ApplicationArea>
   <DataArea>
      <ItemMaster>
         <ItemMasterHeader>
            <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
            <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
            <Classification>
               <Codes>
                  <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
               </Codes>
            </Classification>
            <Classification>
               <Codes>
                  <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
               </Codes>
            </Classification>
            <Classification>
               <Codes>
                  <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
               </Codes>
            </Classification>
         </ItemMasterHeader>
      </ItemMaster>
   </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

---

Note that the `UserArea` element is not copied; I am not sure if that's what you really want or if it's just an omission on your part.

Comment: Interesting. Do you need to specify `xmlns` if you use `xpath-default-namespace`?

Comment: @Parfait Yes, you do. `path-default-namespace` works only on the input; the default namespace declaration works on the output. If you remove it, the added element will become `<Classification xmlns="">`.

Comment: Hi michael, you are right, I made a mistake. Now I have re-edited the expected xml. Yes, I also want to copy the <UserArea>. How to change the xslt? Thanks

Comment: Simply add `<xsl:copy-of select="UserArea"/>` after the added `Classification`.